# New tag request for [basecamp3]

Tags: support, tags

I want to create the [basecamp3](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basecamp3) tag and both ask and answer questions in the long run. I may also post about Basecamp in the future because we do use both Basecamp and Basecamp 3 in our company and I want to distinguish my posts based on the correct application. I've already [asked a question on Basecamp 3](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95242) but the tag was edited. I guess the OP thought that Basecamp and Basecamp 3 were versions or the same application.

If you do approve my tag request could you please also rollback the info that I've entered for this tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that we get enough Basecamp questions here to justify having a version-specific tag. (There have been 15 questions tagged [basecamp](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basecamp) in the 6+ years of this site, and at least one of those is closed.) Are they really that incompatible that they can't use the same tag?

My suggestion is to ask and answer questions using the existing tag, and if (when) it becomes clear that we need to distinguish between the two we can create the other tag.

Comment: Ok, fair enough and logical. I'll do as you say.